# "This post does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: support

"This post does not meet our quality standards." Not sure why I'm getting this. Is there no feedback? Just trying to ask why eurosym is not giving me what I expect. (By the way, I simply get the letter $e$. Hate to be a crab-pot, but I'm being censored on the actual site.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common problem for new users to the site and has been dealt with on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). See [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/168244)

There it is explained that a site-wide quality control is in effect. This filtering mechanism has perhaps incorrectly identified your question as one of "low quality". Some generic rules are in place to catch these, and they may not always be accurate.

Note that the [review page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review) (with a specific [Low Quality Posts category](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats))

[image]

and set of [10K-tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools) (note the post designations within the right column, some of which are flagged automatically by the system)

[image]

act as a second, community-suggested filter for identifying low-quality posts.

The suggestion would be to add some detail to your post in an attempt to overcome the automated system filter that has denied your post to be made.

More than that, don't give up! This is a friendly community that's willing to help!

Comment: Right, I have no idea how the filter works, but forcing myself to expand on the question (after I went and did something else for a bit) did the trick. The question has been accepted: 

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110972/eurosym-seems-to-not-be-working

Thank you!